# Button opens new JFrame multiple times. How do I stop this?

Tags: java, swing, window, jframe, jpanel

I am using to different classes: one holding a main JFrame with a button, and one holding a new JFrame that is called upon at a button press.

```
if( event.getSource() == noteBtn ) { MiniPad.pad(); return;}
```

(MiniPad.pad() references the class and pad() method on the new JFrame)

When I removeAll() on the JPanel that hosts the button, and then revalidate() and repaint(), the button opens the JFrame multiple times, which isn't what I want it to do at all.

Is there a way to tell the MiniPad class that you can't have more than one copy of the JFrame open at any one time? I extend the JFrame by the way, in case that's any help.

Comment: how would you know the frame is closed? if you are waiting for it to close, you could use a boolean value to indicate whether the frame is open.

Comment: This [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9443609/1057230) can give you some idea, though don't use two `JFrame`s, instead stick to one `JFrame multiple JDialog` thingy as very much adviced by @AndrewThompson :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: Everything below is valid programming knowledge, but you might also want to consider having `MiniPad` extend the `JDialog` class instead. I haven't used it before, but its implementation looks a lot like `JFrame`. You might not actually have to change much in your `MiniPad` class. The documentation is here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html

If you're wondering why, check out Andrew Thompson's post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556).

--

From what I understood of your question, `MiniPad` extends `JFrame`, and the `pad()` method creates a new instance of the `MiniPad` class. The simplest solution would be to turn the `MiniPad` class (at least through the `pad()` method) into a singleton. A singleton is a type of class where only one instance (or object) can exist at any given time. By calling a static method (in this case `pad()`) you check to see if an instance of the object already exists; if it does, simply use that existing object:

```
public class MiniPad extends JFrame {

    //whatever code you have

    private static MiniPad padInstance = null; //the singleton instance of your MiniPad

    public static MiniPad pad() {
        if(padInstance == null)
            padInstance = new MiniPad();
        //If you want to reset the object every time you call the method for whatever reason, do it here
        pad.setVisible(true); // I believe this is all you want to do
    }
}
```

This should do what you want. By calling the `pad()` method, only one `MiniPad` will ever show up.

However, if I read your question wrong, let me know and I will revise my answer.

Info on singletons:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: please did you read advice by one of top posters here, then again [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/714968)

Answer (score 3):

The best solution is to open a [modal dialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html) instead of the frame.  See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556) for more.